# String manipulation, removing a tag

Tags: javascript, string

I have the following loop which generates a little snippet of html:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    test_html += 'some text here<hr />';
}
```

this will create the html

```
some text here<hr />
some text here<hr />
some text here<hr />
some text here<hr />
some text here<hr />
```

How do I stop the last `<hr />` from being added, or how do I remove the last `<hr />`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd just use an array.

```
var test_html = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    test_html.push('some text here');
}
console.log(test_html.join('<hr />'))
```

Also, if you want to join only strings, just loop one less

```
var test_html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) { //4 not 5
    test_html += 'some text here<hr />';
}
test_html += 'some text here';
```

Comment: Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 2):

Joining the array is much faster, especially in IE:

```
test_html = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    test_html.push('some text here');
}
test_html = test_html.join('<hr />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    test_html += (i === 4) ? 'some text here' : 'some text here <hr />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test_html = 'some text here';
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    test_html += '<hr />some text here';
}
```

If I was doing this to an array, I'd use [Array.join()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

Comment: why does var = 1 in your version?

Comment: Because I've already added one outside the loop, but that one has no hr in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    test_html += 'some text here';
    if (i < 4)
        test_html += '<hr />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = O; i < 5 ; i++) {
    test_html += 'some text here';
    if (i != 4)
        test_html += '<hr />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var loops = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < loops ; i++) {
 if (i == loops -1)
  {
    test_html += 'some text here';
  }
   else
  {
        test_html += 'some text here<hr />';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    test_html += 'some text here';
    if (i < 4) test_html += '<hr />';
}
```

It will create:

```
some text here<hr />
some text here<hr />
some text here<hr />
some text here<hr />
some text here
```